# React Native IOS on Real Device force closed in Splash Screen

Tags: ios, typescript, iphone, xcode, react-native

React Native ios don't have problem when running on Emulator but when using Real Device force closed in Splash Screen.
this message before force closed
[screenshot message before force close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc1t6.jpg)
Any have same issues?

React Native ios don't have problem when running on Emulator. on Real Device expecting to run like on emulator

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.